# How to update/delete sharepoint list item using kendo Ui

Tags: sharepoint, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo UI to read items from a sharepoint list and it's working fine

but i want to add 2 other buttons to update and delete them.

I understand that theres other types than read: , like update: and delete: Please Help :)

This is my code :

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://server/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items",
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose")
                        }
                    },


                schema: {
                    data: function (data) {
                        return data.d && data.d.results ? data.d.results : [data.d];
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10

            },
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: false,
            scrollable: true,
            groupable: true,
            columns: [{
                field: "Country",
                title: "Country",
                width: 50
            }, {
                field: "Name",
                title: "Name",
                width: 50
            }, {
                title: "Action",
                template: "<a>Edit</a>",
                width: 10
            }, {
                title: "Delete",
                template: "<a>Delete</a>",
                width: 10
            }],

        });
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you have tried and how what you tried differs from what you want. Have you got errors, does some of it work, etc? This will greatly help people answer your question.

Comment: i can display the items in the keno UI grid but i want to add an other bouton to edit the selected item

Answer (score 0):

Here is a documentation article that explains how to configure a Kendo UI DataSource for CRUD operations:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud

Here is a Grid editing demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline

Here is a brief Grid editing documentation:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/editing

Comment: i did created the delete bouton but when i clic on it nothing happen,so i really can't apply the same example in this link because i'm usng a sharepoint list